# Open modal popup from a modal popup in Flex?

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, actionscript, modal-dialog, flex4

Is it possible to open a modal popup from a modal popup? I have not been able to get the following to work by calling showDataEntry() from an open modal popup:

```
// at the top of the modal's mxml, inside <mx:TitleWindow>
import mx.managers.PopUpManager;
import views.windows.MyDataEntry;

...

private function showDataEntry():void {
    var myDataEntry:MyDataEntry = MyDataEntry(PopUpManager.createPopUp(this,MyDataEntry,true));
    PopUpManager.centerPopUp(myDataEntry);
}

...

<mx:Button id="btnDataEntry" label="Data Entry" click="showDataEntry();" />
```

Comment: What error message do you get?

Answer (score 1):

Without knowing exactly what MyDataEntry does, it looks like that may be the problem. Try just creating the popup with and pass it a class to create the content.

```
var myDataEntry:MyDataEntry = PopUpManager.createPopUp(this,myDataEntry,true) as MyDataEntry;
```